# issue in Attempting to fetch sbt

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am student and i am try to install apache spark on Ubuntu when ever i try to
built spark through sbt with sbt/sbt assembly command i find this error 
i have already try to maximize the size of the heap still have not found 
solution to this issue kindly help me through this issue.
the error i found

```
Attempting to fetch sbt
Launching sbt from build/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/

Sometimes when you attempt builds and you don't have enough heap allocated it will bomb out, hence, in the example they increase heap size on the command line before running HelloWorld:

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m HelloWorld
```

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

Comment: here's a similar thread and they appear to have it working at the bottom of the thread after setting sbt -mem = 512: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/quot-sbt-sbt-run-quot-command-returns-a-JVM-problem-td5157.html